# JPA DBUnit Rollback won't work

Tags: java, jpa, dbunit

i have some anoying problems with JPA and DBUnit test (system-tests).

To perform multiple tests, i created a AbtractClass:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context/test-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public abstract class AbstractJPASystemTest {

    private static final String MODULE_IDENTIFIER = "JPASystemTest";

    private Scenario scenario;

    @Resource(name = "dataSource")
    private DataSource ds;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Initialisierung des <code>IntegrationTestDrivers</code>.
     *
     * @param scenario2set
     * @param fixtureFileResolver
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected static IntegrationTestDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new IntegrationTestDriver(IntegrationTestDriverConfiguration.DEFAULT);
        driver.setDataSource(this.ds); // DataSource (DB)
        driver.setSchema("APP"); // zu nutzendes DB Schema
        driver.setCaseSensitiveTableNames(false);
        //this.ds.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false); -- no effect
        this.em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
        this.em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @After
    public void shutDown() {
        this.em.getTransaction().rollback();
        this.em.close();
    }
```

And i have a implementation which is pretty easy like this:

public class TestDetailEntityTest extends AbstractJPASystemTest {

```
/** Zugriff auf die EntityTabelle */
@Autowired
private TestDetailEntityDAO dao;
@Test
public void write() throws Exception {
    //write some Entities to DB
    dao.save(...);
}
@After
public void after() throws Exception {
    driver.verifyDatabaseState();
}
```

The test is running good :)
(so the Test_pre.xml and Test_post.xml -conditions seems to be redeemed )

But if i look into my local derbyDB after all tests or after just this one "write"-Test , there are this Entities still available in my DB.

So, no Rollback was performed.

I'm pretty new to all this JPA,Hibernate,DBUnit, stuff but i searched some solutions and tips to revertd the DB and tried to check every solution the internet had for me, but nothing worked (so far) ....

So maybe someone here has an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you are using Spring did you look at their support for automatically rolling back after a test? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/testing.html#testing-tx